An integration formula that looks like polar coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$
Let $M$ be a complete $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold with non-negative Ricci curvature. Let $x_0\in M$ and $\theta>1$ be fixed. Consider the function $f=\theta^{-1}d(\cdot, x_0)$, where $d$ is the distance function on $M$ and define, for every $\lambda>0$, the function $$F(\lambda)=\frac{1}{n-1}\int \frac{1}{(\lambda+f^q)^{n-1}}dv,$$ where $q>1$ is fixed.
All this stuff comes from the second page of this paper that I am reading. What I do not understand is why we have $$F(\lambda)=q\int_0^{\infty}V(\theta s)\frac{s^{q-1}}{(\lambda+s^q)^n}\, ds,$$ where $V(s)$ denotes the volume of the geodesic ball with center $x_0$ and radius $s$ in $M$.
The author claims that this follows from Fubini's theorem, but I don't see the connection. This formula that we want to prove reminds me of integration in polar coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (I am not extremely experienced with manifolds) where we basically integrate over the boundary of each open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose center is our fixed point and then we integrate over the radius of these balls. I think that the same phenomenon is present here, only that instead of the regular balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ here we have geodesic balls on our Riemannian manifold $M$, but I do not know how to justify this equality. I know that integration in polar coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a particular case of the coarea formula and I know that we have a coarea formula on manifolds too, is this the way to go?
P.S. Sorry if this is way too elementary for this forum, I am a beginner when it comes to analysis on manifolds, but I really try my best to learn this beautiful subject.

Expand the volume element $dv$ in $d$-dimensions. Then, $f$ is exactly the polar distance $s$ divided by $\theta$.

@Jon thank you for your comment, but what do you mean by expanding the volume element? I have never seen this before, could you show me how to do this please?

This is more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com. Perhaps you could migrate it to there.

@DeaneYang okay, thank you, should I just delete the post here and post it there? I am not quite sure how migration works.

I think that’s the easiest way to do it.

@DeaneYang did that, thank you!
